# Process.mainmodule threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application

I am calling console application from the web application in .net core 3.1 but I am getting Main Module error "Process.MainModule threw an exception of type System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
Below is the code where i am trying to trigger my console application.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, Please can anyone help me with resolving this issue?

```html
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Runcase(List<string> products, string runnumber, string button)
        {
            ProductsViewmodel pv = new ProductsViewmodel()
            {
                ProductId = products,
                RunNumber = runnumber
            };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var token = _tokenSource.Token;
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Repos\iSolveConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\iSolveConsoleApp.exe";
                var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
                if (process == null)
                {
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
                }
                else
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    return View(pv);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.productinfo = new MultiSelectList(_context.inputValuesConfigurations, "ProductID", "ProductName");
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a valid data...");
                return View(pv);
            }
            }
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the message of the `Win32Exception`?

Comment: Just for consideration and unrelated to the exception: Why do you use a console app instead of a library? You could even make a lib for the actual functionality, reference and use it here and if you need the same as console app, you can do the same there.

Comment: @Fildor, I want application to perform some functionality even browser is closed. So I am using this approach so even browser is closed console app will continue performing operations.

Comment: That's completely unrelated. You can do that without external process. But alas, you chose this path. There should be a Message and probably an ErrorCode. Can you add them?

Comment: @BiesiGrr, can you please tell me how I can gett Win32Exception message?

Comment: @Fildor, I added few more error images, Does it have message and Error code or I should find somewhere else?

Comment: @Neu you can get the full exception text easily with `Exception.ToString()`, or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup. You haven't posted any exception screenshot though, just a watch window. Did your program really throw?

Comment: @Neu you haven't added any error image, just some watch window screenshots. Some properties can't be evaluated when an application is stopped.

Comment: @Neu what's the *real* problem? Did you try to start an external application and got an error? The process didn't start?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I put my code in try and catch block but it did not throw any exception. But it also did not start console application.

Comment: @Neu in that case you should edit this question, removing the unnecessary screenshots and mentions of an exception, or post a new question. BTW the fact one of the screenshots shows execution at `else` means the process *was* created.  Perhaps it terminated before you had a chance to call `.WaitForExit()`? Perhaps it logged an error? Are you sure you can execute that program *from the web app's directory*?

Comment: @Neu the code doesn't specify a working directory which means the current directory (the web app's) will be used. If that app needs settings files, it won't find them and throw itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you and it make sense. Can you please give me any suggestions on what I should do to specify working directory and make this work? And yes I will edit this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221132/discussion-between-neu-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Set ProcessStartInfo's [WorkingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-3.1) property to the tool's path, eg `@"C:\Repos\iSolveConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"`. You should probably set [RedirectStandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netcore-3.1)  and [RedirectStandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=netcore-3.1) and read the tool's output

Comment: Since that tool is a .NET Core app, you should add error handling and logging to it to. Check the Application log in Event Viewer too. When an application crashes unexpectedly, the exception it threw is logged as an Error event

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I set working Directory and RedirectStandardOutput and  RedirectStandardError and it did not throw exception but getting same watch window and did not invoked console application.

Comment: On the contrary, that screenshot shows the tool already exited - check `ExitTime`. Most likely due to an error. Have you tried running it from the command line? Did you *read* the standard output and error to check for error messages? Have you added logging to the tools to record any exceptions? Checked Event Viewer?

Comment: IIS web apps run under an app pool account that typically *doesn't* have permission to read anything outside the web site's folder.  Allowing web apps to run external processes is a *very serious security risk*, which is why languages like PHP and ASP replaced CGI in the 90s. Most likely your web app has no permission to launch that tool

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I was trying to run exe file from cmd but I got this error message "A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'."

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when you try to access the `MainModule` property. The documentation for this property does not list `Win32Exception` as a possible exception, but looking at the IL for the property it is evident that accessing it may throw this exception. In general it will throw this exception if you are trying to do something that is impossible or not allowed in the OS.

Win32Exception has the property `NativeErrorCode` and also a `Message` that will explain what the problem is. You should use that information to troubleshoot your problem. `NativeErrorCode` is the Win32 error code. We can guess all day long what the problem is but the only way to actually figure this out is to inspect the error code.

But to continue guessing, one source of these exceptions is accessing 64 bit processes from a 32 bit process. Doing that will throw a Win32Exception with the following message:

> A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

You can get the number of bits of your process by evaluating `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Even running as a 64 bit process you will never be allowed to access `MainModule` of process 4 (System) or process 0 (System Idle Process). This will throw a `Win32Exception` with the message:

> Unable to enumerate the process modules.

If you problem is that you want to make a process listing similar to the one in Task Manager you will have to handle process 0 and 4 in a special way and give them specific names (just as Task Manager does). **Note that on older versions of Windows the system process has ID 8.**

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to the directory of .exe for process before Process.Start() helped

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(processExecutablePath);

_opBrowserProcess = Process.Start(processExecutablePath);
```

Comment: Can you please add more explanation to your answer. It has some code but didn't gives a complete understanding in my opinion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).